# ¿Cómo asignarle el valor a una variable a traves de una consulta?

Tags: sql-server

Tengo la siguiente consulta donde dependiendo del id del documento me trae el tipo de producto
siendo una boleta, guía de despacho o factura.
Mi duda es como puedo asignarle a la variable @Cod_Producto el valor del producto que existe en la consulta

```
    Declare     @Id_Documento   as UniqueIdentifier = 'E67F2746-98D1-4D95-A8A2-2FCE780B54F9'
    Declare     @Cod_Producto   as UniqueIdentifier


    Select
        (Case when Det.Cod_Producto = '77BEB092-8F61-4451-A495-AA18451002A5'
         Then coalesce( Cl1.Rut_Completo , Cl2.Rut_Completo, Cl3.Rut_Completo )
         Else Cl.Rut_Completo
         End) As Cliente,
        (Case when Det.Cod_Producto = '77BEB092-8F61-4451-A495-AA18451002A5'
         Then coalesce( Cl1.Cliente , Cl2.Cliente , Cl3.Cliente )
         Else Cl.Cliente
         End) as Nom_Cliente, 
         FDet2.Cod_Producto as Prod_Fact, fdet.Cod_Producto as prod_guia, bdet.Cod_Producto as Prod_boleta
         
    from Ges_NcvCabecera Cab
    inner join Ges_NcvDetalle Det on Det.Id_NotaCredito = Cab.Id_NotaCredito
    inner join Ges_Clientes Cl on Cl.Cod_Cliente = Cab.Cod_Cliente
    Left join Ges_BlvDetalle bDet on bDet.Id_DetalleBoleta = Det.Id_DetalleDocumentoOrigen
    Left join Ges_BlvCabecera bCab on bCab.Id_Boleta = bDet.Id_Boleta
    Left join Ges_Clientes Cl1 on Cl1.Cod_Cliente = bCab.Cod_Cliente
    Left join Ges_GdvDetalle fDet on fDet.Id_DetalleGuiaDespacho = Det.Id_DetalleDocumentoOrigen
    Left join Ges_GdvCabecera fCab on fCab.Id_GuiaDespacho = fDet.Id_GuiaDespacho
    Left join Ges_Clientes Cl2 on Cl2.Cod_Cliente = fCab.Cod_Cliente
    Left Join Gestion.dbo.Ges_FcvDetalle FDet2 With (Nolock)    On  Det.Id_DetalleDocumentoOrigen = FDet2.Id_DetalleFactura
    Left Join Gestion.dbo.Ges_FcvCabecera FCab2 With (Nolock)   On  FDet2.Id_Factura = FCab2.Id_Factura
    Left join Ges_Clientes Cl3 on Cl3.Cod_Cliente = fCab2.Cod_Cliente
    Where   Cab.Id_NotaCredito  = @Id_Documento
```

Imagen del resultado de la consulta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cuál de los campos quieres asignar a `Cod_Producto`?

Comment: dependiendo del documento que salga diferente de nulo en uno de los 3 campos como producto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asumiendo lo que pones lo ejecutas todo como si fuera un script (por ejemplo dentro de una función o un procedimiento almacenado); mi sugerencia:

```
Declare     @Id_Documento   as UniqueIdentifier = 'E67F2746-98D1-4D95-A8A2-2FCE780B54F9'
Declare     @Cod_Producto   as UniqueIdentifier

SELECT
   [Tus columnas que obtienes]
  INTO #TblTEMP -- Colocamos el resultado en una tabla temporal
FROM
   [ TODO lo que tienes de tu consulta]
;
```

A continuación debes usar tu lógica para saber que dato dejar por si más de uno es distinto de `null`; los evaluo del primero al último acorde a la imagen que pusiste.

```
SELECT
  @Cod_Producto = IIF (Prod_Fact NOT IS NULL, Prod_Fact, IIF (prod_guia NOT IS NULL, prod_guia, Prod_boleta)) -- Asignamos el valor; si hay varias filas el valor que tendrá será el del último registro
FROM
   #TblTEMP
;

DROP TABLE #TblTEMP; -- Borramos la tabla temporal
```

Con lo anterior colocará en la variable `@Cod_Producto` el primer valor en el orden que se evalua que no sea `null`.

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Fe de errata: `IIF` el condicional `@Prod_Fact NOT IS NULL` (y demás similares) lo correcto es `@Prod_Fact IS NOT NULL`,

Comment: Me funciono lo que me diste pero la cadena era IS NOT NULL, gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Saludos. Ahora actualizo; no tengo el entorno para probar y lo redacte *usando la memoria* y me falló un poco :D